# Can a class instance take an argument?

Tags: python, class, nlp

For example, if I create a class Vocab and instantiate it with:

```
vocab = Vocab(tokens)
```

Can I use pass an argument like a character or a list of lists of characters to it?
Like:

```
tokenslist = ['a','b','c']

result = vocab[tokenslist]
```

Any further reading on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You say you want to pass an argument which would be a function call with `(...)` but you are using indexing with `[...]`. It's not clear which you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This would be done in the `__init__()` method which acts very much like a constructor.

Example:

```py
class MyTest:

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        #do stuff with the args
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mt = MyTest("foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an instance of a class (with `()` not `[]`), you can defined [`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) on the class. Then instances of it will be callable and you can pass values like any other function:

```
class Vocab:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def __call__(self, arg):
        print("instance called with ", arg)
        return list(zip(self.tokens, arg))


vocab = Vocab([1, 2, 3])

tokenslist = ['a','b','c']
result = vocab(tokenslist)
# result will be [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
# prints "instance called with  ['a', 'b', 'c']"
```